# Building Assimp 3.2 from Source Without Using CMake

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2015, assimp

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in C++. I just got done setting up the newest version of Boost v1.61.0 and boost seems to be working fine. I did this in advance since some of the functionality in Assimp depends on the Boost library. I have downloaded the newest version of Assimp 3.2 from here [Assimp](http://assimp.org/index.html) which is source only. I've read through the documentations, I've, searched here at stack, done google searches and even looked on youtube for how to build this from source code in Visual Studio and I am not able to find anything. Does anyone know the proper procedure to do this? Remember I am not using nor do I have CMake. It does not matter if I create a DLL or Lib. I can link either dynamically or statically; I just want to be able to use the newest version of Assimp in my OpenGL projects.

Comment: You can download CMake for free, it can make a visual studio project file for you.

Comment: @RyanP I guess I'll have to try it, but I've never used CMake before

Comment: It's worth learning. The idea is simple, instead of configuring your project in Visual Studio, or Eclipse, or using a Makefile... you just have to learn how to configure a project in CMake syntax, and then CMake will be able to generate all of those for you depending on which platform and with which tool-set you want to compile.

Comment: @RyanP I was able to generate the solution file for VS2015; I build out ASSIMP a few projects within failed to build; but the actual ASSMIP project within did build and it appears that I have a dll available. I'm in the process of trying to link against it now.

Comment: @RyanP Yes; the libraries worked out; thank you for the advice. It took a little bit to figure out how CMake works; but it isn't all that difficult.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! I've really taken to CMake, I like it a lot.